# Academic Curriculum Vitae Template (possibly in LaTeX)

Tags: cv, latex

It seems that I'll have to prepare my first academic *curriculum vitae* within few weeks. However, I lack a good template to use to organize it.

> ***Question:*** Could you suggest an easy to read yet somehow elegant,
>   "professional" (according to current standard) template for an academic cv (possibly in *LaTeX*)?

I see that there are many cv templates available online, but very few are specifically academic and even less in LaTeX; plus, this is my very first time, so I'd really appreciate experts' suggestions and some guidance.

Thank you.

Comment: I feel like this is a duplicate of: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80/latex-template-for-resume-curriculum-vitae

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is answered on another stack exchange site: [LaTeX template for resume/curriculum vitae](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80/latex-template-for-resume-curriculum-vitae)

Comment: Q says possibly in LaTeX but implicitly open to other alternatives, so different scope to tex.se

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent, I apologize for my ambiguous wording: by 'template' I didn't mean only LaTeX class or a sample MSWord file, but also some guidance in choosing what an undergrad student (prospective graduate) *should* list in his cv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several packages/classes in LaTeX available and you can find a list of many on [CTAN (Comprehensive TeX Archive Network)](http://www.ctan.org/topic/cv). There is no preferred package since CVs can be constructed in many ways, some of which may be specific to fields or academic cultures. The [`moderncv`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/moderncv) class is quite popular and may be a good starting point but you need to figure out if any one format suits your particular needs best.